# What is the best project directory structure for Spring, Spring MVC and Spring Boot projects

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am always confused between the directory structure of a simple spring project, Spring MVC project and Spring Boot project. What is the correct way of defining the directory structure of these projects starting with just a simple Maven project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

The structure is not "ruled" by Spring Framework, Spring MVC, or Spring Boot. It was pretty much standardized by **Maven** a while back and since then nothing has changed...much.

The `src` directory contains all of the source material; it contains a sub-directory for each type:

- `main` for the *main build artifact*
- `test` for the *unit test code and resources*

The `target` directory is used to house all output of the build **by default** ― for Maven. Gradle uses `build` (if I remember correctly) and IDEA comes by default to `out` ― you can, of course, change these to whatever you want.

I think it's wise to stick to this structure since a lot of libraries/frameworks rely on it. Changing it will also make you configure things (sometimes almost impossible) in order to achieve something you would get for free otherwise.

This would be an example:

```
ɐuıɥɔɐɯ@uplink:~/Workshop/java/java-spring-boot$ tree
.
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── LICENSE
├── README.asciidoc
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        └── resources
```